# OTEL Collector tail sampling

Tags: open-telemetry-collector, open-telemetry-java, opentelemetry-tail-sampling

I'm new to tail sampling in opentelemetry collector

can some one explain me the this configurations

**decision_wait** (is otel collector waits/ keeps the trace data in memory for that particular trace_id) ? what is maximum time can we give here, default seems 30s

I want to use trace data for long running jobs/requests, we have one of the message based application, for some messages it runs for minutes/hours..

is it right thing to do tail sampling for this kind application

Documentation https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/tree/main/processor/tailsamplingprocessor